# Rotational energy in wheel and friction. Estimatiion of rubber loss

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, granulated-materials

When an aeroplane wheel touches ground it goes from 0 rpm to say 800 rpm almost in an instant. Rotational inertia causes the wheel to glide on the asphalt and rubber is chipped off. How can I do an at back-of-an-envelope estimation of the amount of rubber shaved off because of friction?
Rotational energy is what ? $J\ddot{\theta}^2$? If this is the energy received by the rubber is during $\Delta t$ how do I proceed from there to obtain a crude estimation of the rubber lost?

Comment: You might be able to compute torques and forces, but material loss would need knowledge of specific material properties.   Same forces on a block of titanium and a block of wood will have different losses.  Friction losses don't necessarily translate into damage/material loss.

Comment: Assuming that tread wear is the most common failure mode, you might be well-served to seek out the MTBF. Another indirect route would be to seek traffic data and correlate it with PM2.5 and below air pollution data.